# diffrence of two input fileds returned in another input

Tags: javascript

I would like to calculate in the simplest way difference of two inputs and return it in the third one.

```
id="incomeSharedSum" - id="expendituresSharedSum" = id="disposalIncome"
```

Here is my form:

```
<label for="%nameRoot%[income]">Total Income:€</label>
<input type="text" data-sumSource=".incomePart<?php echo $personOrder; ?>" name="%nameRoot%[income]" id="incomeSharedSum"/>

<label for="%nameRoot%[expenditures]">Total Expenditures: €</label>
<input type="text" data-sumSource=".expendituresPart<?php echo $personOrder; ?>" name="%nameRoot%[expenditures]" id="expendituresSharedSum"/>

<label for="%nameRoot%[disposalincome]">Monthly Disposal Income: €</label>
<input type="text"  name="%nameRoot%[disposalincome]" id="disposalIncome"/>
```

Appreciate your help on this very basic question. Thank you.

==========EDIT==========21/01/2016

I have some progress but dont know now how to modyfi js to calculate difference rather than sum:

```
<label for="%nameRoot%[income]">Total Income: €</label>
       <input onblur="updateDiff('#disposalIncome');" type="text" data-sumSource=".incomePart<?php echo $personOrder; ?>" name="%nameRoot%[income]" class="form-control disposalIncome" id="incomeSharedSum"/>
<label for="%nameRoot%[expenditures]">Total Expenditures: €</label>
       <input onblur="updateDiff('#disposalIncome');" type="text" data-sumSource=".expendituresPart<?php echo $personOrder; ?>" name="%nameRoot%[expenditures]" class="form-control calc disposalIncome" id="expendituresSharedSum"/>
<label for="%nameRoot%[disposalincome]" class="col-sm-4 field-label">Monthly Disposal Income: €</label>
       <input type="text" data-sumSource=".disposalIncome<?php echo $personOrder; ?>" name="%nameRoot%[disposalIncome]" class="form-control" id="disposalIncome"/>
```

and using this piece of js code:

```
function updateDiff(outputFieldSelector){
    var outputField = $(outputFieldSelector);
    var sum=0;
    $(outputField.attr('data-sumSource')).each(function(){
      sum+=Number($(this).val());
    });
      outputField.val(sum);
```

How to modyfi this line:

```
sum+=Number($(this).val());
```

To get difference (in my case two fields) : Total Income - Total Expenditures = Disposal Income.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function will do the sum and put the value in third textbox

```
function calculateSum()
{
   var incomeSharedSum= parseInt( document.getElementById( "incomeSharedSum" ).value );
   incomeSharedSum = isNaN( incomeSharedSum ) ? 0 : incomeSharedSum;
   var expendituresSharedSum = parseInt( document.getElementById( "expendituresSharedSum" ).value );
   expendituresSharedSum = isNaN( expendituresSharedSum ) ? 0 : expendituresSharedSum ;
   document.getElementById( "disposalIncome" ).value = incomeSharedSum + expendituresSharedSum;
}
```

you can invoke this method on which event (like a button click or blur event of one of the first two boxes)

Comment: How to invoke above using onchange / onblur ?

Comment: adding onblur="updateDiff();" in the first two inputs solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically using `.value` for each of the two input fields, do the subtraction and set the value to the `.value` of the third input field. check this [**JS Fiddle** - *updated* 2](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/Ldbk6qwg/5/)

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('calc'),
  income = document.getElementById('incomeSharedSum'),
  expenditures = document.getElementById('expendituresSharedSum'),
  gTotal = document.getElementById('gTotal');

for (var i in inputs) {
  this.addEventListener('change', function() {
    gTotal.value = +income.value - +expenditures.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<label for="incomeSharedSum">Total Income:€</label>
<input type="text" id="incomeSharedSum" class="calc" />
<br>
<label for="xpendituresSharedSum" class="col-sm-4 field-label">Total Expenditures: €</label>
<input type="text" id="expendituresSharedSum" class="calc" />
<hr>
<label for="gTotal" class="col-sm-4 field-label">final: €</label>
<input type="text" id="gTotal" />
```

---

if you want to add fractions, change the it into this:

```
gTotal.value = (+income.value - +expenditures.value).toFixed(2);
```

where **`2`** is how many digits after the period, if **`0`** it will output integer.

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/Ldbk6qwg/6/)

Comment: Can you please modify it so the calculations are invoke onchange rather than after hitting the button. Thank you.

Comment: @Pela, check it out now

Comment: It is working perfect in JS Fiddle but when I put it my project it is not. What I am getting is: error here [code] gTotal.value = income.value - expenditures.value;[code] <br/>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null(anonymous function) @ sum.js:24
2jquery.min.js:3 The specified value "0000-00-00" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: I even dont know how to format this comments :( I am useless :(

Comment: adding fractions is not needed and is not sorting my problem :(

Comment: I thought you might need adding fractions it is just a suggestion, but I am not sure why are you getting but it looks like you having an input with type of ***date*** or somewhere in your script you excepting a date since it shows `yyyy-MM-dd` and `0000-00-00`

Comment: thank you for your help. I final used solution given by @gurvinder372 and it does the job. Thumb up for both of you.

Comment: Glad for you, you should check his answer then as the correct answer he deserves it more